# Change icon size of tabs

Tags: android

I have difficulty changing icon size of the tab. Could anyone help me increase the size of the icons appearing in tabs ? Thank you in advance.
[Here is the project that I am doing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2sq4YHXzdArUVVJU0FLWURDRlk/view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom view

setCustomView.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.my1, R.drawable.my2, R.drawable.my3};
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtab, null);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      view.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(icons[i]);
      tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view));
}
```

Comment: It will add three new tabs with three icons but texts. I set up the TabLayout with ViewPager so once the program runs, the tabs display in this layout will be populated from the ViewPager adapter's page titles. I have three paper, total I have up to 6 tabs. How to join them together ?

Comment: You can use foreach

Answer (score 4):

you can apply you custom layout within a for loop :

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.searchpin));
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.discussionpin));
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.userpin));

for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    if (tab != null) tab.setCustomView(R.layout.view_home_tab);
}
```

Here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_icon_size"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtab, null);

For those who see only the last tab with the custom view, just put this declaration inside the *for* loop. The rest is the same as Ahmad's.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Andriya, it worked perfectly, if someone wants to add title too you can add text view with text1 id

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/Title.TabWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```