# TabLayout setIcon with a certain size

Tags: android, icons, android-tablayout

I want the icon of my tab to look bigger and I do not know how to do it because it is the first time I use tabs in android.

I am currently putting icons like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        if (i==0)
           tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.perfil);
        if (i==1)
           tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.amigos);
        if (i==2)
           tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.nueva);
        if (i==3)
           tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.notificacion0);
        if (i==4)
           tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.buscar);
    }
```

I thought that maybe you could create a bitmap or similar, give it the width and height that I want, but I do not know how to implement it

I write you the complete code and I hope somebody knows how to help. Thank you very much:

```
public class MainClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_class);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        addTabs(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pestañas);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if (i==0)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.perfil);
            if (i==1)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.amigos);
            if (i==2)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.nueva);
            if (i==3)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.notificacion0);
            if (i==4)
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.buscar);
        }

    }

    private void addTabs(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Tablayout_in_Android());
        adapter.addFrag(new Tablayout_in_Android());
        adapter.addFrag(new Tablayout_in_Android());
        adapter.addFrag(new Tablayout_in_Android());
        adapter.addFrag(new Tablayout_in_Android());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        }

    }


}
```

and the class **Tablayout_in_Android.java**

```
public class Tablayout_in_Android extends Fragment {

    public Tablayout_in_Android() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tablayout_in__android, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching in this forum I found this question that solves the problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424126/change-icon-size-of-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424126/change-icon-size-of-tabshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424126/change-icon-size-of-tabs)

What I have done has been to create the xml and add the code that comes in the answer after assigning each icon to each tab.

Thank you, I hope someone serves you.

I leave the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if (i==0)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.perfil);
            if (i==1)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.amigos);
            if (i==2)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.nueva);
            if (i==3)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.notificacion0);
            if (i==4)
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.buscar);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null) tab.setCustomView(R.layout.view_home_tab);
        }
```